# Angular2 Unique variable setting issue

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

So I've been following a tutorial online and there is a simple login component, but doesn't seem to work as I would expect? I have a login component below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

// Services
import { AuthService } from '../../_services/auth.service';

@Component({
    styles: [require('./login.component.css')],
    template: require('./login.component.html'),
    providers: [AuthService]
})
export class LoginComponent {

    constructor(private _router: Router, private _authService: AuthService) {

    }

    login(form) {
        var email = form.form._value.email;
        var password = form.form._value.password;
        var response = this._authService.login(email, password);
        if (response) {
            this._router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        } else {
            console.log("error");
        }
    }
}
```

Authentication guard which is set on the route `CanActivate`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthService } from '../_services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private _router: Router, private _authService: AuthService) {

    }

    canActivate() {
        console.log("auth: " + this._authService.isLoggedIn);
        if (this._authService.isLoggedIn == true) {
            // logged in so return true
            return true;
        } else {
            // not logged in so redirect to login page
            this._router.navigate(['login']);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally my authentication service to actually take care of the logging in, which in turn sets a variable which is used in my `canActivate` authentication guard.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    isLoggedIn = false;

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    login(username, password) {
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        console.log("set: " + this.isLoggedIn);
        return true;
    }

    logout() {
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
    }
}
```

Now when I run the login function the `isLoggedIn` variable is set to true successfully but when the guard is run when navigating to dashboard the variable `isLoggedIn` is set to false. Now in my mind I would expect it to be true since I set it when the login function is run.

Many Thanx. Ross

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
providers: [AuthService]
```

in your component tells Angular to create and inject an instance of AuthService for each instance of the component. You thus get a different instance of AuthService in the component than the one you get, probably from the NgModule providers, in the other services.

Just remove that line, and declare one and only one AuthService provider in the root NgModule, which will thus be shared by every component and service in the application.

Comment: Excellent! thank you, such a simple mistake. On a side note, would this be a suitable solution for login authentication? I see other tutorials where they set localStorage but from what I know of localStorage is that it can be manipulated by the client. It seems a lot simpler just to use this boolean variable set, or set additional fields when the user is logged in and access such info instead of storing everything in the localStorage.

Comment: If you only store the loggedIn flag in memory, the user won't be logged in anymore if he/she refreshes the page, or opens a link in a new tab, for example. That's why localStorage, or a cookie, is being used. Most of the actual security checks should be done by the backend, not by the frontend anyway, so it should not a problem if the user tries to tamper with the flag. Note that setting the flag to rue in memory just by using a debugger is also quite easy anyway.

Comment: Thank you again. I have used the localStorage but when the app runs I get a internal server error `localStorage is not defined` If I move to /login and login then all works fine and the guard is passed successfully. But not if I direct back to the root, I get the same internal server error. Is there any decent tutorial you can advise?

Comment: No. But an internal **server** error should not be caused by Angular code running on the client.